# How to connect Drupal 7 with Hypertable?

Tags: database, drupal, hypertable

According to http://drupal.org/node/443540:

> Field storage modules could be written
>   to store field data in a variety of
>   ways including HyperTable, Amazon S3
>   or CouchDB

but I have no idea how to do

Answer (score 1):

Despite the documentations, you could have a look on MongoDB module

http://drupal.org/project/mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the Field Storage API documentation page? http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/group/field_storage/7

It's listing the hooks you need to implements to declare a new storage backend ([hook_field_storage_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_storage_info/7)) and to plug a field on a storage backend (hook_field_storage_OP()).